# I am trying to read the last line in my textfile that I have created and have the last line added to my filename before my program exits

Tags: c#

Basically if the file I have created has 4,5,6 in it.  I need to read the file get the number 6 
       out and add it to my filename Ex:(Test-6.txt)yes I want to add the dash also before the file gets 
       to the directory. Can I have some guidance here?

```
    private void BegPinNum_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        FileName2.Text = BegPinNum.Text;
    }
     private void FileName2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        //This is the textbox that displays the filename in it, right now whatever I type in 
          BegPinNum automatically displays here but the rest of the filename I want to get from the 
          last line in the file I created later on in the code
    }
```

There is some code in between this for another textbox, didn't think i needed it here

```
        using (StreamWriter objWriter = new StreamWriter(var1))//I know StreamReader is used for 
              reading the file and I have tried some things but had no luck
             {

                    int numpins = int.Parse(Pins.Text);
                    string basepin = BegPinNum.Text;
                    int pinlength = basepin.Length;
                    string formatspecifier = "{0:d" + pinlength.ToString() + "}" + "{1}";
                    long pinnumber = long.Parse(basepin);
                    string dig = BegPinNum.Text;
                    string result = GetCheckDigit(dig);

                    for (int d = 0; d < numpins; d++)
                    {
                        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dig))
                        {
                            throw new Exception("null value not allowed");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dig = pinnumber.ToString();
                            result = GetCheckDigit(dig);
                        }

                        basepin = string.Format(formatspecifier, pinnumber, result);
                        objWriter.WriteLine(basepin);
                        pinnumber++;
                    }

                    objWriter.Close();  
                    MessageBox.Show("File has been created");
                }

          }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help get you started:

```
string oldFile = "Test.txt";
string number = File.ReadAllLines(oldFile).Last();
string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(oldFile);
string fileExt = Path.GetExtension(oldFile);
string newFile = $"{fileName}-{number}.{fileExt}";

File.Copy(oldFile, newFile);
```